# Xamarin Android Google Maps Fragment

Tags: google-maps, android-fragments, xamarin, google-api

I'm new to xamarin, and I need to put a google map in a aplication.

I have downloaded the example from xamarin of:

https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/MapsAndLocationDemo_v2

and after a few changes, it worked and this project displays the map.

here is the code of the project that works:

/*MainActivity.cs*/

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Gms.Common;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using AndroidUri = Android.Net.Uri;

namespace SimpleMapDemo
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        public static readonly int InstallGooglePlayServicesId = 1000;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.BasicDemo);
        }
    }
}
```

/*BasicDemo.axml*/

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

/*AndroidManifest.xml*/

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionName="4.0" package="com.xamarin.docs.android.mapsandlocationdemo2" android:versionCode="6">
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="14" android:minSdkVersion="14" />
    <!-- Google Maps for Android v2 requires OpenGL ES v2 -->
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
    <!-- We need to be able to download map tiles and access Google Play Services-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- Allow the application to access Google web-based services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!-- Google Maps for Android v2 will cache map tiles on external storage -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- Google Maps for Android v2 needs this permission so that it may check the connection state as it must download data -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <!-- These are optional, but recommended. They will allow Maps to use the My Location provider. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <!-- Notice here that we have the package name of our application as a prefix on the permissions. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.xamarin.docs.android.mapsandlocationdemo2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="com.xamarin.docs.android.mapsandlocationdemo2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
        <!-- Put your Google Maps V2 API Key here. This key will not work for you.-->
        <!-- See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#obtaining_an_api_key -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="apikeytest" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The problem is, than when I try to pass this code to the existing project where I want to add the maps, upon executing it throws the exception:

Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment

The code that fails:

/*SplashScreen.cs*/

```cs
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System.Threading;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views;
using Android.Content.PM;

//using Android.Gms.Common;
using AndroidUri = Android.Net.Uri;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Gms.Common;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android.Gms.Maps;


namespace ProjectWithMap
{

    [Activity(
        Label = "ProjectWithMap",
        MainLauncher = true, 
        Icon = "@drawable/icon",
        //Theme ="@style/Theme.Splash",
        ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait,
        NoHistory = true)]


    public class SplashScreen : Activity
    {
        public static readonly int InstallGooglePlayServicesId = 1000;
        private MapFragment map;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.provaMapa);
        }
    }
}
```

/*provaMapa.axml*/

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="ProjectWithMap.SplashScreen"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

/*AndroidManifest.xml*/

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="projectWithMap.projectWithMap" android:versionCode="6" android:versionName="4.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
    <!-- Google Maps for Android v2 requires OpenGL ES v2 -->
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
    <!-- We need to be able to download map tiles and access Google Play Services-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- Allow the application to access Google web-based services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!-- Google Maps for Android v2 will cache map tiles on external storage -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- Google Maps for Android v2 needs this permission so that it may check the connection state as it must download data -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <!-- These are optional, but recommended. They will allow Maps to use the My Location provider. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <!-- Notice here that we have the package name of our application as a prefix on the permissions. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="projectWithMap.projectWithMap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="projectWithMap.projectWithMap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <application android:label="projectWithMap" android:icon="@drawable/Icon" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <!-- Google Maps V2 API Key -->
    <!-- Para más documentación mirar https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#obtaining_an_api_key -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.V2.API_KEY" android:value="key" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And this code throws me the exception of:

Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment

I don't understand why in one project works and in the other dosen't, I tried to search this error and found multiple solutions, tried all that I fond with no good results...

change com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment

change public class SplashScreen : Activity for public class SplashScreen : FragmentActivity

but nothing worked, always the same error.

What I'm missing? Why it's working in one project and not in the other?...

**EDIT**

It seems that the error is in the manifest, in the point that when I execute, at the Application Output:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.V2.API_KEY" android:value="yourKey" />
```

like it's getting the manifest of google service...

while I have added my key!

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.V2.API_KEY" android:value="key" />
```

what manifest is the aplication geting, the manifest of the app, the manifest of the google service?

**EDIT:**

In the end was a bug of xamarin or visual studio, deleting the manifest and creating it again solved the issue.

Comment: Did you define/include the `SampleMapActivity` class in your project as well? The demo project uses this [here](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/MapsAndLocationDemo_v2/SimpleMapDemo/SampleMapActivity.cs) to implement the layout on which the fragment will be included in.

Comment: I did not define/include the SampleMapActivity, but as it shows the code that works, I don't use it, in the MainActivity I do:
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.BasicDemo); directly, so i go from the main activity to the basicdemo view, and this works in the test project, but not in the real project.

Comment: In the end was a bug of xamarin or visual studio, deleting the manifest and creating it again solved the issue.

Comment: If anybody looing for a google map integration in xamarin android then this will be a useful http://appliedcodelog.blogspot.in/2015/04/build-google-map-v2-in-xamarin-android.html

Answer (score 1):

Add the extra tool

> "Google Play Services"

in the Android Sdk Manager ... and be aware to have just ONE tag "application" (well spelled)

```
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="@string/mapkey"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
</application>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>` permission to the manifest file.